# what is the best data structure for solving TSP in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, branch, genetic-algorithm

I made a program in VB to solve TSP using Genetic algorithm and I use Array list as Data structure , I want to ask  is there another data structure for solving TSP in visual basic better than what I used?
also I will make  a program in VB to solve TSP using branch and bound algorithm , what is the best data structure can I use it in this case or array good for that?
thank you

Comment: Better in what sense? Execution speed (i.e. effective data access and manipulation)? Usefulness for the GA (e.g. good genotype-phenotype mapping)? Please elaborate.

Comment: yas to make program more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know VB, but the following should be general enough.

If the genotypes are directly the city permutations the data structures I use are (for N cities):

- a distance matrix - a N-1 by N-1 2-D array where position (i, j) contains the distance from i-th city to j-th city
- the genotypes are then arrays (or lists) of the city indices (i.e. 0..N-1)

The fitness evaluation is then easy and fast as it is just a single walk through the genotype with constant-time lookups of the distances. If memory is an issue and the problem is BIG (i.e. tens of thousands of cities and more) you might want to consider not storing the whole distance matrix and store only a part of it (if the problem type allows to, like in symmetric TSP where distance from A to B is equal to distance from B to A) or just not to store it at all and compute the distances on demand.

For branch-and-bound approach you basically need the distance matrix too. If you are going to do some distance-based prioritisation over the order in which are the cities chosen and your TSP is a metric one (i.e. each city is a point in a 2D plane) you can use K-D tree for fast lookup of cities nearest to any point in the plane.